# java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: E:\\...\\intermediates\\flutter\\debug\\flutter_assets\\AssetManifest.json

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I'm to get the solution.
I already tried flutter clean, flutter create, flutter get package.

**AssetManifest.json**

{"assets/audio/calling.mp3":["assets/audio/calling.mp3"],"assets/audio/chatsend.mp3":["assets/audio/chatsend.mp3"],"assets/cfg/configurations.json":["assets/cfg/configurations.json"],"assets/fonts/Blacksword.otf":["assets/fonts/Blacksword.otf"],"assets/fonts/proximanova-regular.otf":["assets/fonts/proximanova-regular.otf"],"assets/img/SuccessCheck.flr":["assets/img/SuccessCheck.flr"],"assets/img/apple_pay.png":["assets/img/apple_pay.png"],"assets/img/canada.png":["assets/img/canada.png"],"assets/img/cart_empty_ipmau1.png":["assets/img/cart_empty_ipmau1.png"],"assets/img/china.png":["assets/img/china.png"],"assets/img/clock.png":["assets/img/clock.png"],"assets/img/cod.png":["assets/img/cod.png"],"assets/img/completed.png":["assets/img/completed.png"],"assets/img/deliveryboy.png":["assets/img/deliveryboy.png"],"assets/img/flutterwave.png":["assets/img/flutterwave.png"],"assets/img/france.png":["assets/img/france.png"],"assets/img/germany.png":["assets/img/germany.png"],"assets/img/grocerydefaultbg.jpg":["assets/img/grocerydefaultbg.jpg"],"assets/img/intro1.png":["assets/img/intro1.png"],"assets/img/intro2.png":["assets/img/intro2.png"],"assets/img/intro3.png":["assets/img/intro3.png"],"assets/img/italy.png":["assets/img/italy.png"],"assets/img/loading.gif":["assets/img/loading.gif"],"assets/img/loading_card.gif":["assets/img/loading_card.gif"],"assets/img/loading_circle.png":["assets/img/loading_circle.png"],"assets/img/loading_trend.gif":["assets/img/loading_trend.gif"],"assets/img/location.png":["assets/img/location.png"],"assets/img/loginbg.jpg":["assets/img/loginbg.jpg"],"assets/img/loginbg1.jpg":["assets/img/loginbg1.jpg"],"assets/img/logo.png":["assets/img/logo.png"],"assets/img/malay.png":["assets/img/malay.png"],"assets/img/marker.png":["assets/img/marker.png"],"assets/img/mastercard.png":["assets/img/mastercard.png"],"assets/img/netherlands.png":["assets/img/netherlands.png"],"assets/img/no_data_found.png":["assets/img/no_data_found.png"],"assets/img/noshopfound.png":["assets/img/noshopfound.png"],"assets/img/onthway.gif":["assets/img/onthway.gif"],"assets/img/package.png":["assets/img/package.png"],"assets/img/paymentwaiting.gif":["assets/img/paymentwaiting.gif"],"assets/img/paypal.png":["assets/img/paypal.png"],"assets/img/paypal2.png":["assets/img/paypal2.png"],"assets/img/permission.png":["assets/img/permission.png"],"assets/img/pharmacydefaultbg.jpg":["assets/img/pharmacydefaultbg.jpg"],"assets/img/plate-food2.png":["assets/img/plate-food2.png"],"assets/img/portion.png":["assets/img/portion.png"],"assets/img/prescription.jpg":["assets/img/prescription.jpg"],"assets/img/rating.png":["assets/img/rating.png"],"assets/img/razorpay.png":["assets/img/razorpay.png"],"assets/img/rectangle_loader.gif":["assets/img/rectangle_loader.gif"],"assets/img/resturentdefaultbg.jpg":["assets/img/resturentdefaultbg.jpg"],"assets/img/shop.png":["assets/img/shop.png"],"assets/img/smiley.png":["assets/img/smiley.png"],"assets/img/spain.png":["assets/img/spain.png"],"assets/img/splash.flr":["assets/img/splash.flr"],"assets/img/stripe.png":["assets/img/stripe.png"],"assets/img/united-arab-emirates.png":["assets/img/united-arab-emirates.png"],"assets/img/united-states-of-america.png":["assets/img/united-states-of-america.png"],"assets/img/upi.png":["assets/img/upi.png"],"assets/img/userImage.png":["assets/img/userImage.png"],"assets/img/visa.png":["assets/img/visa.png"],"assets/img/visacard.png":["assets/img/visacard.png"],"assets/img/wallet.png":["assets/img/wallet.png"],"assets/img/winners.flr":["assets/img/winners.flr"],"packages/cupertino_icons/assets/CupertinoIcons.ttf":["packages/cupertino_icons/assets/CupertinoIcons.ttf"],"packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/close.png":["packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/close.png","packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/2.0x/close.png","packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/3.0x/close.png"],"packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/icon_error.png":["packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/icon_error.png","packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/2.0x/icon_error.png","packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/3.0x/icon_error.png"],"packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/icon_info.png":["packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/icon_info.png","packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/2.0x/icon_info.png","packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/3.0x/icon_info.png"],"packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/icon_success.png":["packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/icon_success.png","packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/2.0x/icon_success.png","packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/3.0x/icon_success.png"],"packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/icon_warning.png":["packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/icon_warning.png","packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/2.0x/icon_warning.png","packages/rflutter_alert/assets/images/3.0x/icon_warning.png"]}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @shubham, any solution you found for this. I am also facing same problem